# The true condition does not work

Tags: php, if-statement, substring

I have a string like 'nameabc' in a  PHP function. I check if the last three character of a string is 'abc' it should remove it and return the remaining string.this is my condition:

```
$name="nameabc";
$last_char=substr($name,-4);   //it returns the 'abc'
if($last_char == 'abc')   //this condition does not return true
$real_name=substr($name,0,-4);
```

I do not know what is the problem.

Comment: Probably that `$last_char` is not `'abc'`.

Comment: @FelixKling I echo the `$last_char` and it is `'abc'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$last_char=substr($name,-4);`

If this return as 'abc', probably your variable `$name` have a trailing space. You can check this with `strlen($name)`. It will return 8 instead of 7. That is `nameabc<space>`. So when your print your `$last_char`, it will be printed as `abc<space>` while you could not visualize the space in the screen. It is a good practice to `trim` your variables always.

```
trim($name);
```

And as John's answer, you would require only `-3` to get the last 3 characters.

Answer (score 7):

`substr()` returns `eabc` in [your example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7RhOEL). You need to use an offset of -3:

```
$name="nameabc";
$last_char=substr($name,-3);  
if($last_char == 'abc')
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Tyunhu)